# adding elements to the dom after "upgrading" to select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

select2 works fine on elements added to the dom:

```
$('select').select2({data:['Foo','Bar']});
```

But it's not working if the element is later on added to the dom.

```
function ElementCreator() {
    var elem = $('<select>');
    elem.select2({data:['Foo','Bar']});
    return elem;
}

//creater is called like..
ElementCreator().appendTo('#holder");
```

One Workaround (I don't like this):

```
function ElementCreator() {
    var elem = $('<select>');
    window.setTimeout(function() { elem.select2({data:['Foo','Bar']});},1);
    return elem;
}
```

Is it possible to create a select2 selector, on elements not already inserted in the DOM?

Comment: If you are adding options via ajax call then you have to reinitialize select2.

Comment: No, they are added by an existing array.

Comment: can you please make JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/228630/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself the answer.

This is the problem:

```
 var elem = $('<select>');  //elem contains the select element
 elem.select2({data:['Foo','Bar']});
 return elem;  //elem contains only the "old" select element
```

This is the solution:

```
 var cont= $('<span>');
 var elem = $('<select>').appendTo(container) ;  //cont contains the span + select element
 elem.select2({data:['Foo','Bar']}); //cont contains the span + "old" select + new select2 stuff.
 return cont ;
```